# Necessary and Sufficient Condition for Complete Regularity of Topological Space

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

**Exercise**

I'm attempting the following exercise:

> Fix a subbasis $\mathcal{S}$ of $X$. Prove that $X$ is completely regular $(T_{3\tfrac{1}{2}}$) if and only if for each point $x\in X$ and neighborhood $V\in\mathcal{S}$ with $x\in V$, there exists a map $f:X\to [0,1]$ such that $f(x)=0$ and $f(y)=1$ for $y\in X-V$.

The forward direction is straightforward (assuming I approached it correctly) but I'm having trouble with the converse.

**My Attempt**

$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose that $C\subset X$ is a closed set with $x\not\in C$. $X-C$ is open, so $X-C$ is a union of finite intersections of members of $\mathcal{S}$; for simplicity assume that we can write
$$
X-C=V_1\cap V_2\cap\cdots\cap V_n
$$
for some $V_1,\ldots, V_n\in\mathcal{S}$. Since $x\in X-C$, it follows that $x\in V_i$ for each $i$, and the hypothesis asserts that there exist maps $f_i:X\to [0,1]$ such that $f_i(x)=0$ and $f(y)=1$ for $y\in X-V_i$. Now (by DeMorgan's Law in set theory)
$$
C=(X-V_1)\cup (X-V_2)\cup\cdots\cup (X-V_n).
$$
so it seems that we need to construct some map $f:X\to [0,1]$ such that $f|_{V_i}=f_i$ for each $i$. But I cannot think of an easy way to do this. If I could, then it shouldn't be hard to provide a proof for the general case (that $X-C$ is the union of more than just one finite intersection of elements of $\mathcal{S}$).

**Comments and Concerns**

I thought about defining $f=\prod_{i=1}^{n}f_i$, but when $y\in X-V_i$ and $y\not\in X-V_j$ for some $i\neq j$, there is no guarantee that $f(y)=1$. I also thought of defining $f$ in some piecewise manner, but I would likely lose continuity in this process. Could anyone give me a hint as to go about constructing this $f$? Thanks very much in advance.

**Edit**: I almost forgot to mention: this problem is "part a" in a sequence of exercises which we allowed to assume that all spaces are at least $T_1$; however I don't think it really plays a role in this specific problem.

Comment: Use $\max\{f_1,\dots,f_n\}$.

Comment: Also a great idea! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Let $g=\prod_{k=1}^n(1-f_k)$. Clearly $g(x)=1$. Now suppose that

$$y\in X\setminus\bigcap_{k=1}^nV_k=\bigcup_{k=1}^n(X\setminus V_k)\;;$$

then there is a $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that $f_k(y)=1$, so $g(y)=0$. Now $g$ isn’t *quite* what you want, but ... ?

Comment: ...But $1-g$ is. Brilliant. Thank you very much. Maybe I should've thought about this more before posting.

Comment: @Blake: You’re very welcome. A useful thing to remember is that if you if $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ are functions from some set to $[0,1]$, then $\prod_{k=1}^nf_k$ is $0$ on the **union** of the sets where the $f_k$ are $0$, and it’s $1$ on the **intersection** of the sets where the $f_k$ are $1$. Thus, knowing whether you’re interested in the union or the intersection of some sets tells you whether to ‘flip’ the functions or not.

Comment: I"ll definitely keep that it in mind. It seems like a very useful tool to have that I'm sure will come in handy.